# In tesseract how to draw bounding box around recognised words

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

I'm looking at the tesseract C++ [API](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/api/baseapi.h) and [API examples](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample), I understand that you can get the coordinates of the boxes of each line/region/word/character recognised, with those functions returning `Boxa*`, but how do I draw it onto the original image?

Is there a API function does this? or do I have to save the coordinates and call another library like opencv to do this job?

Comment: is that tesseract or opencv you are talking about?

Comment: Tesseract OCR is "recognition" library, not drawing library. But it is often bundled together with leptonica library, which actually does provide also some drawing functionality. Although I can't recall from head, how much line drawing is supported and how easy it is to use. What do you use to draw original image? That API probably can draw lines too and may be the most familiar API to you. (I did use last time tesseract on Android, and simply used the Android API painter to draw the debug info over Android Bitmap with original image). And opencv is again recognition, not drawing.

Comment: My original image is from a camera, I just want to show user what words on the image are being recognised. You are right tesseract depends on leptonica, I think Boxa type is some kind of wrapper of a leptonica type. I can't find any drawing function in tesseract baseapi.h, I can save the staging image by "GetThresholdedImage and write the image using pixWrite" but I don't think that includes the bounding box. opencv does have a rectangle function to draw boxes, but I just thought tesseract could have something already so I don't have to deal with 2 apis.